# Is it possible to make a Transform parameter have a default and if it is, how?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple **Data** class that will allow me to store certain things in a file for a save/load system, but I do not want to use *everything** the **Data** class offers so I'm writing its parameters as defaults in case I don't use them.

Here is the "minimal" code:

```
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class EntityData
{
    public float[] position, rotation, scale;
    public string exampleString;

    public EntityData(string exampleString = "Default String", Transform transform = new Transform())
    {
        this.exampleString = exampleString;
        this.position = VecToArr(transform.position);
        this.rotation = QuaToArr(transform.rotation);
        this.scale = VecToArr(transform.localScale);         
    }
    //Helper functions
    public static float[] VecToArr(Vector3 vec) { return new float[] { vec.x, vec.y, vec.z }; }
    public static float[] QuaToArr(Quaternion qua) { return new float[] { qua.x, qua.y, qua.z, qua.w}; }
}
```

This of course returns a compiler error `CS0122` because `Transform.Transform()` is inaccessible due to its protection level which I understand.

So my question is, how can I write a **Transform** as a default parameter.

The solution that I had in my head was to create a temporary container struct that would hold a Transform and then use that, but that feels too messy.

*to avoid writing `EntityData** data = new EntityData(//every single parameter)` I need this to be default, because sometimes I won't be needing to use a **Transform** at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an overloaded constructor.

```
public EntityData(string exampleString = "Default String")
{
    this.exampleString = exampleString;
    this.position = default position value;
    this.rotation = default rotation value;
    this.scale = default scale value;
}

public EntityData(string exampleString, Transform transform)
{
    this.exampleString = exampleString;
    this.position = VecToArr(transform.position);
    this.rotation = QuaToArr(transform.rotation);
    this.scale = VecToArr(transform.localScale);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. If I do what you tell me, then yea, I get rid of the problem of not having the default values. But still doesn't solve the issue of not being able to use Transform as an argument.

Comment: I mean two overloaded constructors, you are still able to use Transform as an argument.

Comment: ah fair, my bad. I missunderstood you at first. I'll try implementing that, but I was still hoping to find a nicer looking solution.